# How using HiLo to generate keys with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql?

Tags: entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

In microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver has ForSqlServerUseSequenceHiLo extend method that allows you to [use HiLo to generate keys with Entity Framework Core](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-hilo-to-generate-keys-with-entity-framework-core/). How using HiLo to generate keys with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql?

Answer (score 1):

Library Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql currently does not support the HiLo algorithm to generate keys, but use HiLo algorithm on MySql possible, for example, using [the nuget package NHiLo](https://github.com/fabiogouw/NHilo).